# save post running twice and creating two database entries - how do I disable this?

Tags: actions, save-post

I am developing a job tracking database for my utility engineering company and am having an issue when running a save hook.  I have a task_types db table that tasks are created off of and using a custom meta box on the "cover_page" (post edit screen) of the job I allow these tasks to be created for each job from user input.  It is processing my validation code twice therefor creating 2 database entries and two identical tasks from its task type, which is not correct.  Can anyone assist me with this problem.  See the code snippets below.

```
    // Validate Data    for Custom Meta Boxes
function rfd_argument_function() {
    global $post;
    global $rfd_meta_box_options; 

    foreach($rfd_meta_box_options as $rfd_meta_box_option){
            $meta_box_options[] = $rfd_meta_box_option['meta_box_form_fields'];
    } 

    foreach($meta_box_options as $options){ 
        foreach ($options as $option){ 
            if($option['name']){
                    $arguments = array(
                    'post_id' => $post->ID,
                    'name' => $option['name'],
                    );  
            }
            do_action('save_hook', $arguments);
        }   
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'rfd_argument_function');

// Save data for Custom Meta Boxes
function rfd_save_meta_box_values( $args ) {
$post_id = $args['post_id'];
$name = $args['name'];
$old_data = get_post_meta($post_id, $name);
$new_data = $_POST[$name];

// Autosave, do nothing
 if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
  return;
 }
 // Check permissions
 if ( 'page' === $_POST['post_type'] ) {
  if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) ) {
        return;
  }
 }else {
  if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
        return;
  }
 }
if( $_POST['job-update-action']==='freeze'){ // Freeze associated items updated below in save_rfd_job_update_action.
        return;
}
// AJAX? Not used here
if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) {
        return;
}
// Return if it's a post revision
if ( false !== wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ){
        return;
}

// if new is same as old
if($new_data === $old_data[0] ){ 
     return;
}else{
    // add_post_meta($post_id, 'save-count', 0, true); // add "save-count" if none exists
    // $save_count = get_post_meta($post_id, 'save-count', true); // grab save count 
    // if( $save_count == 0){
        // $save_count++;
         // update_post_meta( $post_id, 'save-count', $save_count );
        if($_POST['task-to-assign'] !== 'Select a Task Type to Assign'){
            global $wpdb;
            $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'task_types';
            $task_type = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE task_name = '" . $_POST['task-to-assign'] . "'", OBJECT);
            $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'tasks'; // Change table
            // check for duplicate task
            $task = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE task_name = '" . $_POST['task-to-assign'] . "' AND job_id = '" . $post_id . "'", OBJECT);

            // rfd_debugger( $task[0],1);
            // if( $task[0]->job_id === false){
                $rows_affected = $wpdb->insert( $table_name, array( 'task_type_id' => $task_type[0]->id, 
                                                                'task_name' => $task_type[0]->task_name, 
                                                               'description' => $task_type[0]->description, 
                                                               'job_id' => $post_id,                                                        
                                                               'assigned' => $_POST['person-to-assign'],                                                        
                                                               'assigned_datetime' => current_time('mysql'),                                     
                                                            ) 
                                        );
            // }
        }

    // }else{
        // delete_post_meta($post_id, 'save-count', 0);
    // }
    update_post_meta($post_id, $name, $new_data); // Add New Data   
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'task-to-assign', 'Select a Task Type to Assign'); // Reset Field
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'person-to-assign', 'Select A Person'); // Reset Field   
}

}       
add_action( 'save_hook', 'rfd_save_meta_box_values');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark this as RESOLVED OR DELETE.  It was caused by a function that I myself created to help with meta box creation.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your

```
 if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
  return;
 }
```

into your `rdf_argument_function()`. Any change?

Comment: nah but thanks... It is caused because in the functions before this that I have created to make my meta box creation more streamlined, I am calling this function many times.  I worked around this by just adding in another function and added a save_post call separate from this.  Sometimes I make myself feel like an jackass and this is one of those times.  lol anyhow thanks again.